# Universality of restricted representations

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$. Given an irreducible representation $\rho$ of $G$, this creates a (possibly reducible) representation $\rho'$ of $H$ obtained by restricting $\rho$ to the elements of $H$.

Is is true that all irreducible representations of $H$ arise in this manner? More precisely, for all irreps $\rho'$ of $H$, is it necessarily the case that there exists and irrep $\rho$ of $G$ for which $\rho'$ is the restriction of $\rho$ onto $H$? If not, is there a simple counterexample to this claim?

If true, this would say that restricted representations are somehow "universal" in that the irreps of $G$ give rise to all irreps of its subgroups by restriction. However this doesn't seem immediately obvious. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Indeed, this is not always the case. A representation of $H$ with this property is said to be extendible to $G$, and there are a lot of results on when this holds.

Comment: For instance, take $H$ to be a non-identity abelian subgroup of a perfect group $G$ -- the only irrep of $H$ that is a restriction of an irrep of $G$ is the trivial rep. Explicitly, $H=A_3$ is a subgroup of $G=A_5$.

Comment: Perhaps I should mention however, that there will always be an irreducible representation of $G$ such that the given representation is a constituent of the restriction to $H$.

Comment: A smaller counterexample is $H=A_3$ is a subgroup of $G=S_3$, but every one dimension representation of $G$ is trivial on $H$, and the two dimensional rep is reducible when restricted to $H$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft  Thanks for the reply. Do you know of any references which characterize when a representation of $H$ is extendible to one of $G$?

Comment: For the complex case, there is quite a bit about it is Isaacs' book on character theory of finite groups, though there will probably be sources that contain even more.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Thank you for the counterexample.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Is there a simple proof of the above fact, that for every irrep $\rho'$ of $H$ there exists an irrep of $G$ for which $\rho'$ is a constituent of the restriction to $H$?

Comment: This is essentially what Frobenius reciprocity says.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I'm slightly confused; I thought that Frobenius reciprocity says that given an irrep $\rho'$ of $H$, one can construct a (possibly reducible) induced representation of $G$ which has the same character on $H$ as $\rho'$. Are you stating that this induced representation of $G$ is necessarily irreducible? Or am I missing something? Thanks for the input.

Comment: No, there need not be any representation of $G$ that agrees with the given one on $H$ (that would make the representation extendible). The induced representation will have the original as a constituent when it is restricted, and if the original is irreducible, this will also be true of the irreducible constituents of the induced representation.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Just to clarify: what will also be true of the irreducible constituents of the induced representation? That each of them, when restricted to $H$, will have the original as a constituent?

Comment: Yes, precisely.